# How to receive the vlan header/l2 header using a ICMPv6 socket

Tags: c, network-programming, icmp, icmpv6

In my ND daemon, i am using `rbos_socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);` to receive ICMPv6 header for receiving NS and other ND messages (`l3` messages).
With this option kernel will strip the `l2` header (with VLAN information). which option should I use to avoid this stripping?

My intent is to receive ICMPv6 message with VLAN information.

Already tried using the following:
1) `rbos_socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);`
2) `rbos_socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, PROTO_ND)`

My expectation is to receive ICMPv6 message with `l2` information (specifically VLAN header).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the first VLAN tag like this. It does get stripped from the packet, but it is available out-of-band in the `tp_vlan_tci` and `tp_vlan_tpid` members, see `linux/if_packet.h` (assuming this is on Linux).